# Specifyin "enum" in a using statement - does it make a difference?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, enums, language-lawyer, compiler-bug

A "sanity check" question for language lawyers / nitpickers:

In this snippet of code:

```
enum my_enum { AValue1, AValue2 };

using alias_1 = enum my_enum;
using alias_2 = my_enum;
```

can there be any sort of difference between `alias_1` and `alias_2`? That is, may a compiler treat them differently somehow? My best understanding is that the answer is "no", but a user of mine is experiencing different compiler behavior with the first kind rather than the second kind of statements, when using MSVC 16.8 + CUDA. Something like `cannot convert argument 1 from 'my_enum' to 'alias_1'`.

Notes:

- Pathologies like `#define enum` or name hiding are relevant to address in answers, I suppose, but I'm mostly interested in a "non-pathological" situation.
- Asking specifically regarding C++11 in case it matters.
- I'm finding it difficult to create an MWE, since I don't have that compiler myself nor do I usually run Windows.

Answer (score 1):

The only difference I can think of is that with the usage of the keyword `enum` (as in [elaborated type specifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/elaborated_type_specifier)), the non-type names will be excluded from name lookup.

(emphasis mine)

> The *class-name* or *enum-name* in the elaborated type specifier may either be a simple identifier or be a [qualified-id](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers#Qualified_identifiers). The name is looked up using [unqualified name lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/unqualified_lookup) or [qualified name lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/qualified_lookup), depending on their appearance. **But in either case, non-type names are not considered**.

E.g.

```
enum my_enum { AValue1, AValue2 };

int main()
{
    int my_enum;
    using alias_1 = enum my_enum; // works; refers to the enum my_enum
    //using alias_2 = my_enum;    // doesn't work; the non-type name my_enum in main() is found
}
```

Comment: I was implicitly assuming no hiding, but this is a valid answer. Other than hiding, though, is there anything?

Comment: @einpoklum There is name hiding in `using alias_2 = my_enum;`. With the usage of `enum`, non-type names are excluded then name hiding issue goes away. Other than that, I can't think of other differences.

Comment: Yes, I understand. I should have clarified that's not the crux of what I'm after. So, your answer is fine but see edit.